# Where does Oracle store message properties for AQ messages?

Tags: oracle

We create messages with various properties, like this:

```sql
    message :=  sys.aq$_jms_message.construct(0);
                  message.set_string_property('a', v_a));
                  message.set_int_property('b', v_b);
                  message.set_int_property('c', v_c);
                  message.set_string_property('d', v_d);
    DBMS_AQ.ENQUEUE(queue_name         => SOME_QUEUE,
                    enqueue_options    => queue_options,
                    message_properties => message_properties,
                    payload            => message,
                    msgid              => message_id);
```

And now I'm wondering where the message properties are actually stored.

Answer (score 2):

General process to create an AQ

1. create an Object type
2. create a Queue Table
3. create the Queue

The queue message (1) is stored in a queue table (2).  You can view a list of queue tables by looking at `ALL_QUEUE_TABLES`.

Comment: Sorry, typed my question with too much distraction. I meant to ask for the message properties, not for the messages themselves. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @stmoebius -  The message attributes are stored in the Object Type (1).  Since this ADT is an Oracle supplied data type,  you may need to contact Oracle Support to resolve your issue mentioned in your other thread.